# How to install Python3 and GCC 7 in the same SCL shell?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, gcc, rhel7, devtoolset

I am trying to install [graph-tool](https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/-/wikis/Installation-instructions) on a RHEL7 within a virtual environment; it uses both, Python 3 and gcc 7 or above.
I am unable to use both of them within the same scl bash shell.

```
[root@ ~]# scl enable rh-python36 bash
[root@ ~]# python -V
Python 3.6.3
[root@ ~]# gcc --version | grep gcc
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
[root@ ~]# exit
exit
```

```
[root@ ~]# scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
[root@ ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@ ~]# gcc --version | grep gcc
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
```

Is there a way to update gcc within the first environment (`rh-python36`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by following the below steps:

1. enable the virtual environment containing the Python3

```
[root@ ~]# source /jupyter/bin/activate
(jupyter) [root@ ~]# which python
/jupyter/bin/python
(jupyter) [root@ ~]# python -V
Python 3.6.3
```

2. enabled devtools afterwards:

```
(jupyter) [root@ ~]# scl enable devtoolset-7 'bash'
[root@ ~]# python -V
Python 3.6.3
[root@ ~]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
```